# when launching felix the command prompt is blocked

Tags: command-line, apache-felix

when I m trying to launch felix using

```
java -Xmx100m -jar bin\felix.jar
```

or using

```
java -jar bin/felix.jar
```

the command prompt is blocked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download felix.zip from this tutorial
 http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~diacones/tp-osgi/ 
, put in in c:/  and try again , i have the same problem before i do this now it's ok  ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I found the problem i have to put felix.jar under sdk/jre/lib/ext